# Name in common to refrigeration and heat pumping

Tags: thermodynamics, terminology, definition

I'm struggling while re-visiting gas laws and some of their applications. Graduates and Googling explain refrigeration and heat-pumping, as if dependent on the refrigerant's gas-liquid changes of state. This has led me to ask how these questions can best be answered:

1. Is there a class name for the ('apparently reverse') heat transport involved in refrigeration and heat pumping?
2. Can that type of heat transport be achieved in principle (however inefficiently) solely by gas compression and expansion without a change of state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding 1, for a a liquid-vapor refrigeration/heat pump cycle the heat transports are the results of isothermal evaporation and condensation of the working fluid. The evaporation and condensation are reversible for an ideal reversible cycle.

Regarding 2, a refrigerator/heat pump can be achieved in principle without a change in state. An example is the reversible Carnot refrigerator/heat pump operating on an ideal gas. The heat transports are the results of reversible isothermal expansion and compression of the gas.

Hope this helps.